# Ansible tags not recognized during a play?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
```

I have a playbook called `site.yml` that just contains other playbooks. Some playbooks I only want to ron when I use a `--tags update` tag, but some playbooks I want to run all the time, but only certain tasks tagged appropriately. In my example below, I want all the tasks on the `prepare-update.yml` playbook to only run on `update` tag, while I want to run the `postgresql.yml` playbook all the time. I then want to control some tasks to run or not in my `postgresql` role

```yaml
- import_playbook: prepare-update.yml
  tags: update
- import_playbook: postgresql.yml
```

the `posgresql.yml` playbook simply contains a `postgresql` role

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ var_host | default('exa_site') }}"
  become_method: runas

  roles:
    - postgresql
```

Now my `postgresql` role's `tasks/main.yml` has

```yaml
---
# tasks file for postgresql
- include_tasks: install_postgresql.yml
- include_tasks: run_postgresql_queries.yml
- include_tasks: install_pgadmin4.yml
```

and my `install_postgresql.yml` task has these tasks. As you can see I use 3 different tags, namely `new_install`, `update`, and `uninstall`

```yaml
- block:
  - name: Download app
    win_get_url: ...
  - name: Install app
    win_shell: ...
  tags: new_install

- name: Start service
  win_service: ...
  tags:
  - new_install
  - update

- block:
  - name: Stop service
    win_service: ...
  - name: Delete service
    win_file: ...
  tags: uninstall
```

When I run the following, I expect some tasks to run based on their tags.

```sh
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml -e var_host=my_host --tags new_install site.yml
```

However, I just get this, where nothing runs.

```
PLAY [10.227.x.x] *******************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************
ok: [10.227.x.x]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************
10.227.x.x               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Why are my tasks tagged as `new_install` not being run at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your `include_tasks` are skipped, since they do not contain any tags matching `new_install`.

What you can do, if you don't want to repeat your lower level tags on the `include_tasks`, is to tag them with the special tag [`always`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never).

So, the *main.yml* task of your role becomes:

```yaml
## Using a block, so we can tag them all at once.
- block:
    - include_tasks: install_postgresql.yml
    - include_tasks: run_postgresql_queries.yml
    - include_tasks: install_pgadmin4.yml
  tags: always
```

Another way would be to **import** your tasks, rather, as this is the main difference between `import_*` and `include_*` modules.

So, once again, the *main.yml* task of your role changes to:

```yaml
- import_tasks: install_postgresql.yml
- import_tasks: run_postgresql_queries.yml
- import_tasks: install_pgadmin4.yml
```

Note the difference of wording in the synopsis of the two modules:

- *`import_tasks`: Imports a list of tasks to be added to the current playbook for subsequent execution. <sup>[source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html)</sup>*
- *`include_tasks`: Includes a file with a list of tasks to be executed in the current playbook. <sup>[source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html)</sup>*

So, when one *"blindly"* imports for further execution, the other include them and run them at the same time.
With that in mind, it makes sense that the latter, `include_tasks` would be skipped if missing the proper tag, when the first one would place the tasks in the playbook and then, at the execution of the playbook, the tags on the imported tasks would be evaluated has you were expecting it.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(The solution is described in the other answer by @β.εηοιτ.βε)</sup>

To understand the logic of this problem two points are important:

1. Quoting from [Includes: dynamic re-use](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#includes-dynamic-re-use)

> "Ansible processes included files and roles as they come up in a playbook."

2. Quoting from [Adding tags to includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#adding-tags-to-includes)

> "... tags on an include_* task apply only to the include itself, not to any tasks within the included file or role."

As a result, **when --tags are declared** (on the command-line or otherwise) a play will skip any include_* statement if tags (declared on this include_* statement) do not match. In other words, in this case, a play does not know what's inside an include until the play reaches the include statement and will never learn because it will be skipped.